# How do I delete files from the directory using python

Tags: python, file

want to delete pdf files from the directory using python.
Having "pdffiles" name folder in that lost of pdf are there So I want to delete all files from it but don't want to delete folder, want to delete just file from folder. how can I do it.(may be using `os.remove()`)

Comment: No this is not remove all folder . want to remove all files from folder

Comment: @Mike Scotty, Thanks its working......

Answer (score 4):

Try `listdir`+`remove`:

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('directory path'):
    if i.endswith('.pdf'):
        os.remove(i)
```